# Python: Error during Queue put of a Json object

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

I'm trying to put a JSON object into a queue.

```
ips_q = queue.Queue;  
for ip in ips:
  item = {'ip': ip, 'timeout': 1}
  ips_q.put(item)
  ips_q.join()
```

The line `ips_q.put(item)` gives the error:

```
 TypeError: put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

One required argument is being provided, so what is the meaning of this error?

Comment: can you show some more code?  IE. where did `ips_q` come from?

Comment: @StephenRauch ips_q basic queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `queue.Queue`. The following:

```
import queue
ips_q = queue.Queue
item = {}
ips_q.put(item)
```

errors with:

```
TypeError: put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

This runs without error:

```
import queue
ips_q = queue.Queue()  # instantiate the queue.Queue
item = {}
ips_q.put(item)
```